# Azure DotNet/Core Push Notifications Package

Tags: ios, asp.net, .net, azure, coreclr

Using the linked tutorial it appears as though the dependency on Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs is necessary to send push messages through the Azure Notification Hub. Unfortunately this is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0, It is however compatible with 4.5.

Is there a corresponding package that is core compatible?
Searching the docs hasn't revealed much.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-ios-get-started-push/

Comment: Don't think there is nuget package or sdk for notification hubs is there for .net core. But you can try using the REST API for notification hubs which can be called from any client app supporting http https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/azure/dn495631.aspx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is Azure Notification Hubs package compatible with .NET Core?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38313390/is-azure-notification-hubs-package-compatible-with-net-core)