# Is Azure Notification Hubs package compatible with .NET Core?

Tags: c#, azure, uwp, .net-core, azure-notificationhub

I'm working with a .NET core app, and I see some Azure packages are not compatible, for example **NotificationHubs** and **SendGrid**:

```
Package Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs 1.0.5 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0)
The dependency SendGrid.CSharp.HTTP.Client 2.0.4 does not support framework .NETCoreApp, Version=v1.0
```

I only tried adding NotificationHubs and SendGrid. I haven't even tried any ActiveDirectory packages yet.

Does anyone have any idea if some of these packages will be compatible soon? Or maybe I'm doing something wrong? Or is there a way in a .NET core app to reference an older package?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you deploying on Azure or on a Linux environment?

Comment: I'm deploying to Azure. I had everything working with RC1 and saw .NET core was officially released. I am testing to see how difficult it would be to migrate everything to .NET core and I'm having difficulty with some of the Azure stuff... :(

Answer (score 6):

[Update 11/30/2017] [Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs 2.0.0-preview1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs/2.0.0-preview1) compatible with .NET Core has just been published.

---

[Original answer] As of mid-July 2016 Azure Notification Hubs SDK is not available for .NET core. The product team is working on it, but there's no ETA yet.

At the moment, there are two ways to work around it:

- Use `WindowsAzure.Messaging.Managed` Nuget package as described in [Getting started with Notification Hubs for Windows Universal Platform Apps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-windows-store-dotnet-get-started-wns-push-notification/)
- Through [REST APIs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn223264.aspx). ([List of methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn495827.aspx).)

Comment: The word on the street is that it should be published within the next two weeks.

Comment: @NikitaG. In 7 days we shall see how well you read the future.

Comment: @lucuma, the ETA for a preview release is still the end of next week. From what I understand it will be a preview in the sense that the API has been finalized (identical to the existing one), but internals may need to get tweaks here and there if customers report stability issues that slipped through the testing.

Comment: @NikitaG. Where are you getting your information? I'm not doubting what you say, I'd just like to know where to watch for a release.

Comment: @TastesLikeTurkey, I used to be on the product team and asked someone from there. My understanding is that it will be published to [Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs NuGet package feed](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs/)

Comment: @NikitaG. Any word on this? I really want to get push notifications into my app, but unfortunately waiting on this package is what's holding up the whole works.

Comment: @TastesLikeTurkey, sorry, I was away and just saw this. I asked someone on the team to check what's the latest and respond here when they have the information. They will update here in the comments soon. Sorry for the delay.

Comment: @NikitaG. No problem! Thanks for the info!

Comment: @kspearrin, I apologize for the uncertainty. I'm told that the package is in the process of being published already. Both the package and an Azure update (since there's quite a bit of change) related to it are coming this week.

Comment: [Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs 2.0.0-preview1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs/2.0.0-preview1) has been published about an hour ago.

Comment: @NikitaG. Thank you for keeping us posted!

Answer (score 3):

If you are working on Azure, you are not required to use `netcoreapp` to use ASP.NET Core. You can still use ASP.NET Core with the Full Framework by targetting `net461` instead of `netcoreapp1.0` and it will still work, Azure has the Full Framework available and they are both compatible with the same version of [NetStandard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/standard/library).

We have several Web Apps that run on `netcoreapp1.0` and others on `net461` due to package dependencies (like Azure SDKs), and all run on ASP.NET Core.

When the product team start releasing the .Net Core App compatible packages, just re-target `netcoreapp1.0` and add the `Microsoft.NETCore.App` package and it will keep working.

[Sample github repo of an Azure Web App using ASP.Net Core with Full Framework](https://github.com/ealsur/mvpstream)

Comment: Thanks for all the helpful advice. Since we are still a couple months away from release because we are still building the mobile app, I figured I would try to get the web app using the latest core, instead of updating it after going live. Unfortunately I probably won't be able to do that. Even adding a reference to a .NETStandard class library won't work....   Package Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient 2.1.0 is not compatible with netstandard1.6 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.6)

Comment: Is there a way I can mark both of these answers as accepted? They both give great advice for how to proceed. Thanks again.

Comment: Do not add the reference to NetStandard, just use `net461`, check the [repo's project.json](https://github.com/ealsur/mvpstream/blob/master/project.json) :)